# C#: Inherit from DbContext in Net Core, Constructor: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I currently have PropertyApplication DbContext as below,

```
public partial class PropertyContext : DbContext
{
    public PropertyContext()
    {
    }

    public PropertyContext(DbContextOptions<PropertyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BoundaryChangeEvent> BoundaryChangeEvent { get; set; }
```

I would like to inheritance from this PropertyDbContext. Is this being done correctly in the constructor? Attempting to make unit test pass below,  it overrides save changes to bring in auditing user information. Just curious if specifically the constructor statements below look correct? Or should I try to attempt option 2 below with AuditablePropertyContext options?

```
public class AuditablePropertyContext : PropertyContext
{
    private int _user;

    public AuditablePropertyContext()
    {
    }

    public AuditablePropertyContext(DbContextOptions<PropertyContext> options, UserResolverService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _user = userService.GetUser();
    }

    public void ApplyCreatedBy()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<ICreatedByUserId>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var entity in modifiedEntities)
        {
            entity.Property("CreatedByUserId").CurrentValue = _user;
        }
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ApplyCreatedBy();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

**Option 2:**

I was receiving error trying to conduct this,

```
public AuditablePropertyContext(DbContextOptions<AuditablePropertyContext> options, UserResolverService userService)
    : base(options)
{
    _user = userService.GetUser();
}
```

Error:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions IPTS.PropertyManagement.Infrastructure.Auditable.Data.AuditablePropertyContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions IPTS.PropertyManagement.Infrastructure.Data.PropertyContext '

*Sometimes company utilizes SQL Server, sometimes InMemory, or SQLite

**Unit Test is failing:**

```
services.AddSingleton(a =>
{
    var mock = new Mock<IUserResolverService>();
    mock.Setup(b => b.GetUser()).Returns(5);
    return mock.Object;
});

services.AddDbContext<PropertyContext>(
    options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Ipts").UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll),
    ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
services.AddSingleton<DbContext, PropertyContext>();


services.AddDbContext<AuditablePropertyContext>(
    options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Ipts").UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll),
    ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
services.AddSingleton<AuditablePropertyContext>();

services.RegisterMappingProfiles(new ApplicationServicesMappingProfile(),
    new PropertyManagementDataMappingProfile());
return services;
```

}

**Unit Test: Error**

```
Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
Stack Trace: 
DbContextServices.Initialize(IServiceProvider scopedProvider, IDbContextOptions contextOptions, DbContext context)
DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor **PropertyContext** class to the following code:

```
public PropertyContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

then change the constructor **AuditablePropertyContext** class to the following code:

```
  public AuditablePropertyContext(DbContextOptions options, UserResolverService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _user = userService.GetUser();
    }
```

**notice:** Delete the default constructor in both classes when you don't need it.

Comment: not sure why team wanted it this way, but I think they want to keep it like this?    maybe created another constructor on top of this? my unit test is still failing anyway, thanks- public PropertyContext(DbContextOptions<PropertyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

Comment: @AlanSmith5482 This is a logical change, and it is common.

Comment: hi it works !!  quick question, what would be the consequence if I left this as a constructor, while adding the new on you provided? I want to keep my old teammates code intact,    public AuditablePropertyContext(DbContextOptions<PropertyContext> options, UserResolverService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _user = userService.GetUser();
    }

Comment: feel free to thumbs up question also

Answer (score 0):

You could also provide the specialized `DbContextOptions<Repo>` only on the concrete subtype.

eg

```
public abstract class BaseRepo: DbContext
{
    public BaseRepo(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}


public sealed class Repo : BaseRepo
{
    public Repo(DbContextOptions<Repo> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: hi it works !!  quick question, what would be the consequence if I left this as a constructor, while adding the new one you provided? I want to keep my teammates code intact,    public AuditablePropertyContext(DbContextOptions<PropertyContext> options, UserResolverService userService)
        : base(options)
    {
        _user = userService.GetUser();
    }